# wcf alternatives for instant messaging

Tags: .net, wcf, websocket, xmpp, mqtt

We are developing a windows 8 store app which at some point will require the ability to instant message among the client apps.

I am the backend guy writing php scripts and my friend is the .net guy writing c# code.
Now I do not know much about c# and wcf services but he told me that wcf service can be used for instant messaging and he had tested that it works, so we should continue with our project.

So we continued to write the code. Now we reached that phase that our app must be able to actually communicate.

Now the problem is, the .net guy is saying that the wcf client callback contract service that he had tested earlier is working fine for desktop apps but is not working with the metro apps.
He says he had to make an object of wsDualHttpBinding and wsDualHttpBinding is not supported by windows 8 app platform for metro apps.

Now I dont know much about wcf and c#, but my question is that if he is correct at his side, what alternatives should we go for?

Should we go for the XMPP or MQTT or something else like that? Or is he missing something that might fix the issue? I would also like to know if web-sockets could play any significant role here!

Comment: Side note: Please try to limit amount of text unrelated to your problem. Consider this discussion on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MS ecosystem there are several options for using WebSockets:

- ASP.NET (requires that the server be windows 8 or 2012), can run in the same port than your web app.
- XSocket.NET: http://xsockets.net/
- SuperWebSocket: http://www.supersocket.net/
- Alchemy Websocket: https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/Alchemy-Websockets
- WebSocketListener: https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener
- SignalR: https://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: And what about other parts of the question?

Comment: It is difficult to asset which protocol do you need without take a close look to the requirements. You will have to make specific questions about those protocols and how they fit in your ideas. For a simple chat, XMPP could be an overkill.